# Job I posted listed at multiple companies

Tags: support, jobs

I build online presences for companies as a freelancer, but I also work for a company full time where I do all recruiting. I have a job posted for this company (Backbase) http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/backbase

I also created the company presence for a company called strangelove, and somehow, the job that I posted for Backbase also shows up in the jobs section of the Strangelove career page, see: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/strangelove

How can I workaround this or can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Any job listing you post will be automatically linked to your company page and you can only have one company page per account. The only way to get around it is to have separate accounts per company page.

If you create a new account, email careers@stackoverflow.com and I can transfer the company page (or listing).